# How to extract keyword from a list of various pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have a list in python with lots of url, I have made a loop to downloaded all on a carpet in mi desktop. So far, each one of the pdf has this kind of name: document0,document1,.....,documentx

What i am trying to do is to extract keywords from every single pdf file but so far i´ve been unable to figure out the way to do that.

```
"""
Created on Tue Aug 17 11:03:34 2019

@author: xxxx
"""
#This code is for only one of the pdf but I want do it for each one with 
#the characteristics described above.
import os
os.chdir("//DOCUMENTS/")
import PyPDF2
import re
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("document3.pdf")
NumPages=object.getNumPages()
String="USD" 
for i in range(1, NumPages):
    PageObj = object.getPage(i)
    print("this is page " + str(i))
    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    # print(Text)
    ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
    print(ResSearch)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extract keywords.  Do you want to count the number of time the word USD appears, find all the words containing USD, or something else?

Comment: Hi Patrick, whay i mean is that I want to count the number of times the word USD is mentioned on the pdf file

Comment: So what output are you getting now with your code?

Answer (score 1):

A quick way of doing shell style name matching is using the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.  Below, I rewrote your code to return a generator of matches from a pdf file.  We then add together the counts of all such matches for all the documents.

```
import os
from glob import glob
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def search_page(pattern, page):
    yield from pattern.findall(page.extractText())

def search_document(pattern, path):
    document = PdfFileReader(path)
    for page in document.pages:
        yield from search_page(pattern, page)

pattern = re.compile(r'USD')  # Or r'\bUSD\b' if you don't want to match words containing USD

count = 0

for path in glob('//DOCUMENTS/document*.pdf'):
    matches = search_document(pattern, path)
    count += sum(1 for _ in matches)

print(f"Total count is {count}")  # "Total count is {}".format(count)
```